# How to calculate this mass.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determinate the mass of portion of spherical surface given by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2a^2$ who is inside of the cylindrical surface given by the equation $(x^2+y^2)=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$, knowing that the density at the point $P(x,y,z)$ is given by $\rho(x,y,z) = k(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

I don't know how to find the integration limits, because the graphic is so strange :( If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are interested, we are on the way of finding the proper limits. First of all, note that there is a nice symmetric throughout the equations so, I restrict myself to consider the $x>0,y>0,z>0$. If you have a nice imagine, you'll find out that we should multiply the result by $8$. Working on $$(x^2+y^2)=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$$ gives us $$y/x=\sqrt{\frac{2a^2-1}{2a^2+1}}=k$$ so we found a nice range for $\theta$: $$\theta|_0^{\arctan{k}}$$ Other limits are easy to find. Indeed, $$\rho|_0^{\sqrt{2}a},~~\phi|_0^{\pi}$$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks. Have a shining day Amy. :-)

Comment: @Babak I shall! You too, my friend!